# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

We are attempting to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 box.  We keep running into errors at the end of the install - "the service did not respond to the start or control in a timely fashion".  After that it shows "Failed" under Database Engine Services, SQL Server Replication, Full-Text Search and Reporting Services.  The SQL Server service will not start after this completes.

I have found several answers about installing SQL Server 2008 SP1 prior to the install of SQL Server, so we tried that.  But we keep getting the same errors.  We also tried SP2 with the same problem.

We have also searched and gone through multiple articles about registry permissions, folder permissions, users accounts, etc.  Nothing is working - same error every time.  So far we have been working on this for 2 days.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a known issue with SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008 R2.  The OS does not support SQL 2008 R2 out of the box, but does support it with SP1 or higher.

So I slipstreamed SP2 into the installation and it went through with no errors.

The article I used for this is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it wasn't a UAC issue, have you tried installing on another box (or vm) to see if it happens there too? If it does, I'd say it's bad media.

Comment: Good idea, I will try that tonight and see what happens.